# How to teach a parabolic function to a neural net

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, keras, neural-network

I am aiming for a sequential neural network with two neurons capabale of reproducing a quadratic function. To do this, I chose the activation function of the first neuron to be `lambda x: x**2`, and the second neuron to be `None`.

Each neuron outputs `A(ax+b)` where `A` is the activation function, `a` is the weight for the given neuron, `b` is the bias term. Output of the first neuron is passed onto the second neuron, and the output of that neuron is the result.

The form of the output of my network is then:

[image: formula]

Training the model means to adjust the weights and biases of each neuron. Choosing a very simple set of parameters, ie:

[image: formula]

leads us to a parabola which should be perfectly learnable by a 2-neuron neural net descibed above:

[image: formula]

To implement the neural network, I do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Define function to be learned:

```
f = lambda x: x**2 + 2*x + 2
```

Generate training inputs and outputs using above function:

```
np.random.seed(42)
questions = np.random.rand(999)
solutions = f(questions)
```

Define neural network architecture:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1],activation=lambda x: x**2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1],activation=None)
])
```

Compile net:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
```

Train the model:

```
history = model.fit(questions, solutions, epochs=999, batch_size = 1, verbose=1)
```

Generate predictions of `f(x)` using the newly trained model:

```
np.random.seed(43)
test_questions = np.random.rand(100)
test_solutions = f(test_questions)

test_answers = model.predict(test_questions)
```

Visualize result:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(test_questions, test_solutions, c='r', label='solutions')
plt.scatter(test_questions, test_answers, c='b', label='answers')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

The red dots form the curve of the parabola our model was supposed to learn, the blue dots form the curve which it has learnt. This approach clearly did not work.

**What is wrong with the approach above and how to make the neural net actually learn the parabola?**

Comment: Why is the batch size equal to one in your code? Ideally, you should train on the entire dataset, but that'd require too much time if it's too large (one thousand observations shouldn't be too much for this simple network), so one has to resort to batches. A batch of _one_ element provides too little information, IMO. You could try using a much higher `batch_size`, like 100

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider increasing it next time. For now, I have found an answer without increasing it (probably training is not very efficient, you are right).

Comment: Why not? I think it did learn it, see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Zabob's answer. You have used Adam optimizer which is sensitive to the initial learning rate, and while it is considered quite robust, I have found that it is sensitive to the initial learning rate- and can result in unexpected results (as in your case where it is learning opposite curve).  If you change the optimizer to SGD:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01))
```

Then in less than 100 epochs, you can get an optimized network:

[image: Plots]

Answer (score 6):

### Fix using proposed architecture

Decreasing a learning rate to `0.001` does the trick, compile like this instead:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
```

Visualize new results:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(test_questions, test_solutions, c='r',marker='+', s=500, label='solutions')
plt.scatter(test_questions, test_answers, c='b', marker='o', label='answers')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Nice fit. To check the actual weights to know what parabola exactly was learnt, we can do:

```
[np.array(layer.weights) for layer in model.layers]
```

Output:

```
[array([-1.3284513, -1.328055 ], dtype=float32),
 array([0.5667597, 1.0003909], dtype=float32)]
```

Expected `1, 1, 1, 1`, but plug these values back to the equation

[image: formula]

Coefficient of `x^2` term:

```
0.5667597*(-1.3284513)**2 # result: 1.0002078022990382
```

Coefficient of `x` term:

```
2*0.5667597*-1.3284513*-1.328055 # result: 1.9998188460235597
```

Constants terms:

```
0.5667597*(-1.328055)**2+1.0003909 # result: 2.000002032736224
```

Ie the learnt parabola is:

```
1.0002078022990382 * x**2 + 1.9998188460235597 * x + 2.000002032736224
```

Which is pretty close to `f`, ie `x**2 + 2*x + 2`.

Reassuringly, the difference between the coefficients of the learned parabola and the true parabola is less than the learning rate.

---

### Note that we can use an even simpler architecture

ie:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1],activation=lambda x: x**2),
])
```

Ie we have a neuron with output (a*x+b)**2, and through training `a` & `b` are adjusted -> we can describe any parabola like this as well. (Did actually try this too, it worked.)